# Series $\frac{k^2}{k!}$ with $ k=1$ to $\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

A practice Math Subject GRE asked me to compute
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2}{k!}$. The sum is equal to $2e$, but I wasn't able to figure this out using Maclarin series or discrete PDFs. What's the most elementary way to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Bell numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number)?

Comment: This is a duplicate (probably several times).

Comment: @Did I'm not surprised, but [site](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=k^2%2Fk!) and [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fmath.stackexchange.com+%22k^2%2Fk!%22) searches were insufficient to find duplicates.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No theory needed; you can solve this with simple manipulations.

$$
\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{k^2}{k!} = \sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{(k-1)!} = \sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{k+1}{k!} = \sum_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} + \sum_1^{\infty} \frac{k}{k!} = e + \sum_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} = 2e
$$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the power series

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} = e^x$$

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left [x \frac{d}{dx} f(x)\right] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^2 x^k}{k!} = (x+1) e^x $$

Plug in $x=1$ and the stated result follows.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to calculate the more general series:
$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k^n}{k!}$$ where $n$ is an integer number and $n\ge 0$.

\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}
S_n &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k^n}{k!} \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^n}{k!} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{((k-1)+1)^n}{k!}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(k+1)^n}{(k+1)!} &k\to k+1\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(k+1)^{n-1}}{k!} &\text{simplifying}\\
 &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\left( \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j}k^j\right) &\color{green}{\text{binomial expansion}}\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k^j}{k!} &\color{red}{\text{rearranging}} \\ 
&=  \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j} S_j
\end{aligned}
\end{align}

Now, if you are already familiar with [Bell numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number), this will certainly ring a *bell*; otherwise it's a useful recursion relation to calculate the sum in the general case.

For $n=0$, by definition we know it's [Euler's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29) $S_0=e$. For $n=1$, we have:

$$S_1=\binom{0}{0}S_0=1 \times e = e$$

For $n=2$, which happens to be what has been asked, we have:

$$S_2=\binom 1 0 S_0 + \binom 1 1 S_1 = 2e$$

And so on. In general, since $S_n$'s have the same linear recursion relations as [Bell numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) $B_n$, the solution would be $S_n=e B_n$.

A beautiful way of constructing these Bell numbers would be using the triangles which I've found in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131795/bell-numbers-recursions-bijections):

\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
1 & & 1 & & 2 & & \color{red}5 & & 15 & & 52 & & \color{blue}{203} \\
& 2 & & 3 & & 7 & & 20 & & 67 & & 255 \\
& & \color{red}{5} & & 10 & & 27 & & 87 & & 322 \\
& & & 15 & & 37 & & 114 & & 409 \\
& & & & 52 & & 151 & & 523 \\
& & & & & \color{blue}{203} & & 674 \\
& & & & & & 877
\end{array}

Comment: @ABlumenthal I actually noticed the pun, after I made it $:)$.

Answer (score 1):

$e^x=1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots+\dfrac{x^k}{k!}+\cdots$

Differentiating both sides,

$e^x=0+1+\dfrac{2x}{2!}+\cdots+\dfrac{kx^{k-1}}{k!}+\cdots$

Multiplying both sides by $x$,

$xe^x=x+\dfrac{2x^2}{2!}+\cdots+\dfrac{kx^k}{k!}+\cdots$

Again differentiating both sides,

$(x+1)e^x=1+\dfrac{2^2x}{2!}+\cdots+\dfrac{k^2x^{k-1}}{k!}+\cdots$

Now putting $x=1$ gives,

$2e=\dfrac{1^2}{1!}+\dfrac{2^2}{2!}+\cdots+\dfrac{k^2}{k!}+\cdots$